# Is it possible to sort buckets in Terms aggregation response on a non-term field?

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation

I need to sort the buckets in result of a ElasticSearch Terms aggregation.
Below is the one of the indexed records in ElasticSearch

```
{"personId":"10","Salary":10000, "Age":20, "personName":"xyz"}
```

I am using Terms aggregation over the field Salary. Below is the Terms aggregated ElasticSearch query:

```
{
    "aggs" : {
        "genders" : {
            "terms" : {
                "field" : "Salary"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This query returns the buckets on the basis of Salary values. These buckets can be sort over the Salary value using order below query:

```
{
    "aggs" : {
        "genders" : {
            "terms" : {
                "field" : "gender",
                "order" : { "_term" : "asc" }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I need to sort buckets on any the field `Age` (non terms field), is there any way to do it ?

Comment: Can you show us the mapping you're using?

Comment: Please add a concrete example with expected results to make your question clear.

Answer (score 2):

The whole point of aggregations is to "dispatch" the documents into buckets, each of which is defined by the declared field of the `terms` aggregation, in your case `Salary`.

The buckets you get in the response are not documents anymore. For instance, in the bucket `10000`, you'll get the count of documents which have `Salary: 10000`, and you'll have as many buckets as different `Salary` values there are in all your documents (by default only 10 buckets, though).

So, since buckets are not documents, and since a bucket can aggregate documents with different `Age` values, it's not clear how you'd like the `Salary` buckets to be sorted by `Age`.

Maybe, one way out of this could be to add a `terms` sub-aggregation on the `Age` field, so you get top `Salary` buckets and below that you get `Age` buckets. Then you can sort your `Salary`/`Age` bucket pairs any way you want.