# Elasticsearch: sort terms aggregation buckets by non-key column

Tags: elasticsearch

**Data**

I have objects persisted in an ES index. Each of them has a **myKey** and **myName** string fields (persisted as keyword fields). There is no guarantee that **myName** will always be the same for the same **myKey**. E.g. the following two entries share the same **myKey** but have different **myName** values:

```
{
  "myKey": "123asd",
  "myName": "United States",
  ...
},
{
  "myKey": "123asd",
  "myName": "United States of America",
  ...
},
{
  "myKey": "456fgh",
  "myName": "United Kingdom",
  ...
}
```

**Challenge**

I need to select and return all distinct **myKey** values, find and display the most likely **myName** (most occurances within the context of **myKey**) AND sort the resulting buckets by **myName**.

So far I managed the following:

1. Select the distinct **myKey** values by using a **terms** aggregation.
2. Select the corresponding first **myName** value to each **myKey** by using a **top_hits** aggregation.
3. Sorted by **myKey** using the order clause of the terms aggregation.

This is the code of the aggregation:

```
"aggs": {
"distinct": {
  "terms": {
    "field": "myKey",
    "order": {
      "_key": "desc"    <----- this sorts the buckets by myKey
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "tops": {
      "top_hits": {
        "size": 1,
        "_source": {
          "includes": ["myName"]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I read up on the [ES documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation-order) explaining how one can introduce a second aggregation returning a single metric. This appears to address numeric field only though. *myName* is not numeric.

Is there a way to sort the buckets in ES by *myName*?

Any help greatly appreciated.

### Edit on 2. Sept 2020

Based on the asking of user @joe, current and the expected result are as follows.

### Current result

As it is apparent, the sorting of the buckets is based on the key: `123asd` comes before `456fgh`:

```
"aggregations" : {
  "distinct" : {
    "buckets" : [
      {
        "key" : "123asd",
        "tops" : {
          "hits" : {
            "hits" : [
              {
                "_source" : {
                  "myName" : "United States"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "key" : "456fgh",
        "tops" : {
          "hits" : {
            "hits" : [
              {
                "_source" : {
                  "myName" : "United Kingdom"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

### Expected result

The task is to sort the buckets based on the extra selected field myName: `United Kingdom` comes before `United States`:

```
"aggregations" : {
  "distinct" : {
    "buckets" : [
      {
        "key" : "456fgh",
        "tops" : {
          "hits" : {
            "hits" : [
              {
                "_source" : {
                  "myName" : "United Kingdom"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "key" : "123asd",
        "tops" : {
          "hits" : {
            "hits" : [
              {
                "_source" : {
                  "myName" : "United States"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By doing `_count:desc`, you've only ordered the top agg alphabetically...

Have you tried the following which looks for the most frequest `myName`s under a given `myKey`?

```
{
  "size": 0, 
  "aggs": {
    "by_key": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "myKey",
        "order": {
          "_key": "desc"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "by_name": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "myName",
            "order":{
              "_count": "desc"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Or are  you looking to sort the parent `myKey` agg by the result of the child `myName` agg?

---

EDIT

Sorting a parent agg by the result of a multi-bucket child aggregation results in the following error:

> Buckets can only be sorted on a sub-aggregator path that is built out
> of zero or more single-bucket aggregations within the path and a final
> single-bucket or a metrics aggregation at the path end.

In other words, what you're trying to achieve is not possible and here's [nicely explained why](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30327788/8160318).

Had your child aggregation been numeric (or single-bucket), it would've been [possible](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation-order).

For now your only option appears to be post-processing (or rather post-sorting) the current response in the frontend (or wherever you're using these aggs).

Comment: Dear @joe, I'm looking for the latter: to sort the parent `myKey` by the result of the child `myName` agg.

Comment: Could you also provide what the desired response would look like? I'm having trouble understanding how this sorting would behave.

Comment: Please see the edited answer - both the current and the expected result list are demonstrated. Thank you for taking the time.

Comment: This was also my conclusion, but I thought I'm simply stuck and there must be another way. I think that this is a basic case that is trivial to solve with most other systems (e.g. SQL), hence I was quite baffled to see that it is not possible.

Comment: Right. If you really need it like you defined, nearly everything is possible using scripts (more specifically scripted_metrics). Have a look at some of my other posts -- maybe you'll find some inspiration there: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A8160318+scripted_metric&mixed=0